# Why is sharpness lost in my DSLR viewfinder?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, nikon-d7000, viewfinder, diopter

I have a fairly new Nikon D7000 (I've taken about 2000 pictures).

Something happened during my last trip, where thew viewfinder never gets sharp anymore. It always looks out of focus, regardless if i am in manual or automatic mode.

Pictures still come out sharp, and when I switch to the LCD screen I can see the focus, but not in the viewfinder.

Is there some sort of tuning that needs to be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Nikon viewfinder suddenly fuzzy?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27448/why-is-my-nikon-viewfinder-suddenly-fuzzy)

Comment: @mattdm - Since the other one is not so clear and has no accepted answer... probably because of such a strange description, if it is indeed the same problem... I would close the other one or ask the asker some clarifying questions.

Comment: Yeah, this one is certainly more clear. No pun intended.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You certainly knocked the diopter adjustement out of place. It is there to compensate for people who need eye-glasses.

[image]

With your eye looking through the viewfinder, adjust the knob on the upper right side until you see what is in focus clearly sharp.

Comment: Most (if not all?) also have a little bump/marker for ±0, if you happen to have good eyesight (which seems likely if you're not aware of diopter adjustment knobs).

Comment: ok, now i feel like a complete moron for not figuring this out. also i never knew about the word "diopter", i bet i'll start hearing it everywhere now :) thanks!

Comment: Not all unfortunately. I do find it odd that it is not marked on a good number of DSLRs. Looks like it is on the D7000 (see image) but on the D4 it is not and neither on Pentax K-5 variants, although it is impossible to accidentally change it on the latter since you have to remove the eye-piece to access it.

Comment: How can I reset it to factory settings if there are no indicators for the no of turns made ?

Comment: No. Factory settings do not affect physical dials like this one since it moves a lens inside the viewfinder.

Comment: wow, diopter. I had no idea what that little knob was for. Thanks for the info