# D200 diopter setting

Tags: dslr, diopter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calibrate the diopter correction on my DSLR’s viewfinder?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/how-do-i-calibrate-the-diopter-correction-on-my-dslrs-viewfinder)

I've messed up the diopter setting on my Nikon D200. I tried to set it up manually, but I don't feel comfortable with how I have it at present.

I have a perfect vision; does any one know the setting for perfect vision (As in where the knob should be)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a personal setting. Even if you have "perfect vision", you want to set this to a custom setting for yourself. Put the camera on a tripod, autofocus the camera at something bright with good texture, and adjust the diopter to your liking. Some DSLR's have a marking at the "default" position, but not all. Personally I don't believe the default position matters, as you should decide the best spot for it to sit.

Comment: I've found that the best way to set the diopter is to forget about the scene. Use a blank wall or something similar, turn on the grid display, and adjust for sharpness of the grid. It's as close to coplanar with the groundglass surface as to make zero difference to the eye, and using the grid eliminates the possibility of focus errors or depth of field in the scene affecting the adjustment. (Coincidentally, my presbyopia/myopia combination means that my old Nikons set full-blast one way are perfect with glasses, and full-blast the other way without. Saves twiddling.)

Comment: @Stan perhaps you meant to post this as an answer, not just a comment?

Comment: @StanRogers If I had a grid display, I would do this!

Comment: @Imre - no, it's a comment. I realise that the grid thing is camera-specific. **dpollitt**'s answer is more general, was already accepted, and my refinement is available to anyone who searches.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there is no perfect setting really. And if there is a mid-point/default, it's generally just a reference to which way is +/-.

It's not only for people with a difference in vision, it's also for people who use glasses while shooting.

As said above, adjust it to your liking. After some googling it looks like you can get eye cups/pieces with a +1.0 or -0.5 grade so assist.