# What might make focus points blurred/gone from viewfinder on Canon T2i after cleaning?

Tags: canon, focus, canon-550d, repair, viewfinder

The red lights are all but lost in my T2i now....barely a haze of a blur. The focus points work fine, and I get the audible beep, but I have to check my focus point on the back before shooting and I'm afraid very soon I'll miss a great shot because of it.

This all happened a few weeks ago when I was cleaning my camera. I don't know if maybe I touched a sensor or something by accident that I wasn't supposed to.

Any ideas or help would be very appreciated.

Comment: got the same problem too when i was cleaning my camera yesterday and I've clean the focusing screen, is there any possible way to fix it and not to buy a new focusing screen ?

Comment: some of the red dots are blurry more like big square point

Answer (score 10):

There are two main possibilities I can think of.  The easiest is that you may have inadvertently adjusted the diopter setting on your view finder.  This would make the entire thing look slightly blurry.  If this is the problem, fixing it should be as simple as adjusting the diopter dial near the viewfinder itself.

The other potential problem is that the focusing screen may have been knocked out of alignment.  The focusing screen is a small screen on which the focus dots and lights are displayed.  This screen can be changed and can be accessed (though it is a little tricky) by going in through the lens mount and looking up towards the viewfinder.  If this has been bumped out of position, you may be able to get it back in position or have a camera service shop do it for you quickly (it shouldn't be an expensive operation as focus screens are generally designed to be replaceable.

Answer (score 1):

More likely you have to check your diopter settings. Link below may help.

[How do I calibrate the diopter correction on my DSLR's viewfinder?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/how-do-i-calibrate-the-diopter-correction-on-my-dslrs-viewfinder)

http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=970348

Comment: @mattdm  I will include this link in the post.. :)