# Sharp photo taken, but blurry in viewfinder (Nikon D5200)?

Tags: nikon, digital, viewfinder, display, nikon-d5200

I'm using a Nikon D5200. Until recently, the image in the viewfinder was  clear after focusing. I was able differentiate the blurry part and clear part. But for the past few days I've noticed that images that were focused and captured by the shutter were not clear in the viewfinder.

What could be possible reasons to see blurry images in the viewfinder, but be clear and focused captured photos?

I've cleaned the image sensor using the camera's built-in option. I've also cleaned my lens front element using dry cloth. Neither cleaning solved the problem.

Comment: Also see [How do I calibrate the diopter correction on my DSLR's viewfinder?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/how-do-i-calibrate-the-diopter-correction-on-my-dslrs-viewfinder)

Comment: @mattdm It worked.

Comment: Cool. There should be a button somewhere here where you can agree that this question is a duplicate of the earlier one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has the *diopter adjustment dial* on the back of the viewfinder been moved? If everything was clear to your eyes before moving it will make everything in the viewfinder blurry to your eyes.

The diopter adjustment wheel is pretty much in the same position across most major camera brands. It is provided to help users who wear glasses (or need to) to adjust the viewfinder to match their prescription so that not only the image from the lens is as clear in the viewfinder as it will be to the sensor, but so the information provided by the camera in the viewfinder is also clear.

[image]

To adjust it simply look through the viewfinder and turn it until everything in the viewfinder display (focus points, exposure information, etc.) is sharp. You may have to use a half press of the shutter to light everything up while you adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that the viewfinder eyepiece is clean, and that its diopter adjustment wheel is adjusted for most comfortable viewing.  If poorly adjusted, it could be not just uncomfortable to focus your eyes, but impossible, leaving everything blurry.
2. There could be possible physical damage to the camera, eg the mirror assembly or ground glass screen.  Go to a service centre or knowledgeable camera store for advice.